# Regex key values from string

Tags: php, regex, string, decimal

I've a string of key value pairs with a comma as a delimiter.
I need to go through the string get the key and value and push them into an array.

I'm having an issue with writing a Regex as the value is a decimal number.
An example of the string is as follows:

```
 value,0.23,word,0.42,dog,0.28000000000000014,cat,0,car,17.369999999999997
```

Any idea how to write a correct regex?

Regex just gives me a headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$values = array_chunk(explode(',', $string), 2)

foreach ($values as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = $pair;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help Jack. Not exactly what I was looking for but your solution is great! And I learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex to get the key, value pairs.

```
([a-z]+),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iG7fB6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$str = 'value,0.23,word,0.42,dog,0.28000000000000014,cat,0,car,17.369999999999997';
$parts = explode(',', $str);
$result = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($parts); $i+=2) {
    $result[$parts[$i]] = $parts[$i+1];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  ["value"]=>
  string(4) "0.23"
  ["word"]=>
  string(4) "0.42"
  ["dog"]=>
  string(19) "0.28000000000000014"
  ["cat"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["car"]=>
  string(18) "17.369999999999997"
}
```